# How do I remove hard coded seeds from the bitcoin source code?

Tags: blockchain, blockchain-fork, private-blockchains

I'm experimenting with blockchains at home and in my debug logs are lots of errors showing that my nodes are trying to get addresses from the hard coded seed nodes, I know I can use `connect` to turn off this behaviour but I don't want to have to include that in my `bitcoin.conf` file.
I am using Bitcoin v0.10.

Any hints greatly appreciated :)

Comment: If u wanna turn off the hard-coded seeds (or DNS) AND also not give explicitly the topology you wish to connect, how will u even do any p2p communication? U will need to connect to peers in some way right

Comment: I intend to add them manually in the config file with `addnode` but I keep getting annoying connection errors in my debug log. I just want to turn off the feature that tries to connect to the hard coded seeds.

Comment: There is a seed vector (for TestNet or Regtest) of hard-coded seeds that gets populated in the source code (vFixedSeeds in src/chainparams.cpp i guess?). U can either comment out them or simply clear the vector to empty it. Then u can explicitly have your topology

Comment: I appreciate the help, i have already done that though - https://github.com/derrend/bitcointemplate/blob/master/src/chainparams.cpp
Im looking at `src/chainparamsseed.h` and `share/seeds/`, I think these may be what I am looking for.

Comment: Please paste the error. I can help u

Comment: Thank you viesweshn92 but the mods i made to `src/chainparamsseeds` have fixed my problem, I will supply a more detailed answer below later. Thanks again :)

Comment: Awesome then! Kindly upvote my answer/comment ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways to do it, I personally went into `src/net.cpp` and commented out the `if` condition that triggers the lookup starting at line 1266.

```
// if (addrman.size() == 0 && (GetTime() - nStart > 60)) {
//     static bool done = false;
//     if (!done) {
//         LogPrintf("Adding fixed seed nodes as DNS doesn't seem to be available.\n");
//         addrman.Add(Params().FixedSeeds(), CNetAddr("127.0.0.1"));
//         done = true;
//     }
// }
```

Another effective fix was to remove all the encoded seed nodes from the two arrays located in `src/chainparamsseeds.cpp`

Answer (score 0):

There is a seed vector (for TestNet or Regtest) of hard-coded seeds that gets populated in the source code (vFixedSeeds in src/chainparams.cpp i guess?). U can either comment out them or simply clear the vector to empty it. Then u can explicitly have your topology

Answer (score 0):

the seed nodes are generated in contrib/seeds

curl -s http://bitcoin.sipa.be/seeds.txt > seeds_main.txt
    python makeseeds.py < seeds_main.txt > nodes_main.txt
    python generate-seeds.py . > ../../src/chainparamsseeds.h

just edit seed.main.txt